# Baire class one function whose has countable points of discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a Baire class one function whose has countcountable points of discontinuity.

One of example is Thomae's function, i.e.,

$$f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lll}
       \frac{1}{q} & , x=\frac{p}{q}, p,q \in \mathbb{Z}, gcd(p,q)=1, q>0\\
       1 & , x =0\\
       0 &, \mbox{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

Is there other of such function?

Answer (score 1):

What about the entier function $x \rightarrow \lfloor x \rfloor$ ?

Os any finite sum of step functions? Or take counytably many such functions, ensuring convergence.

Comment: why is the entire function Baire one?

Comment: Write it as a limit of continuous functions